# iframe tables overflowing in iOS while scrolling

Tags: css, iframe

Currently I have embedded an iframe in coinfan.net/prices. However, the scrolling is not as responsive on mobile devices as I would like it to be. The code I have used is:

```
    <div style=“overflow-x: auto !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;“><iframe style=“width: 100%; background: #fff;display:block;” src=“/*pagelink*/” scrolling=“no”></iframe></div>
```

Any recommendations for improving the responsiveness?

Regards,
Ganesh

Comment: https://www.carsonshold.com/2017/01/iframe-tables-cause-overflow-scrolling-on-ios/

Please look into this, hope this help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843680/responsive-on-mobile-device-with-tables-not-working-within-iframe