# How to control div height on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden div element which appears when a button is clicked.

https://handybin.com.au/ (Book Online)

I set the div width and height in css:

```
.booking-inner-popup {
    width: 80%;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 40px auto;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

I use jQuery to set the width and height relative to the browser viewport using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    jQuery('#BookingFrame').css('height', windowHeight * 0.9 | 0);

    jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
        var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        jQuery('#BookingFrame').css('height', windowHeight * 0.9 | 0);

    });

});
```

This works fine in browser and on Android (In that it provides scrollbars for content out of view) BUT it does not work on Apple devices (no scrollbars).

When viewing on an iPad - the height extends well past the bottom of the screen which cuts off the bottom of the form, including the submit button and restricts anyone from using the form.

I have googled and tried a few solutions but none of them work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I applied the settings as outlined in links provide to working versions:

1. Changed the jQuery to resize the wrapper-div
2. Added scrolling to wrapper div
3. Set iframe height=100% and scrolling="no"

https://jsfiddle.net/oleymedia/f4L6skmy/

Does not work.

Desktop: The iframe sets its height to 100% of the div height
iPad: Still no scrolling

Comment: Try to use native js

Answer (score 0):

iFrames on mobile Safari always stretch to fit all available content. You should look this question here: [IFrame height issues on iOS (mobile safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320046/iframe-height-issues-on-ios-mobile-safari) - But wrapping your iframe on a div and setting the height constraint on that div should work.

Comment: He not mentioned that he used iFrame.

Comment: I noticed that by going to the link he provided. Sorry, I didn't explained that.

Comment: He has an iframe inside the modal.

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo the css in the OP is the div that wraps the iframe which has a height of 90vh

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But in the mobile safari, you won't be able to set the iframe height. You could add another wrapping div, with `overflow-y:scroll`. The link I posted above is explaining this issue.

Comment: Did that - still not working - and it breaks the desktop as well

Comment: You don't need to set the div height with javascript/jquery. You should set the iframe height to be equal as its document size.

If your iFrame source is on the same domain as your page, you try something like:

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#BookingFrame').load(function(){
      $(this).height($(this).contents().find('body').height())
        })
    });