# Issue in displaying PDF using Iframe in IOS Safari

Tags: reactjs, pdf, iframe

I am developing a responsive web app using React and try to use iframe to display PDF.

However, I found that only one page can display in iframe under IOS Safari.

I have read this stackoverflow but this is not work in PDF.
[IFrame height issues on iOS (mobile safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320046/iframe-height-issues-on-ios-mobile-safari)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    base64Pdf:"XXXXXX"
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <iframe
            src =  {this.state.base64Pdf}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I would like to ask the solution to display all PDF pages in iframe under IOS Safari.

May I have any advise?

Comment: You can use pdfJs for PDFs. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/