# the Iframe css style is not working on the Iphone, how to fix this?

Tags: html, css

I set my iframe height to be 200px and my the width to be 100% of the layout i set for the ifram
in android it works fine but in Iphone(that i have), the css code doesnt work and it the result is that : the ifram takes the full height and width of its content. which makes everything messed up
this is the code:

```
    <!-- css code -->
<style>
 .pc1s1iframe{ 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>

<!-- html code --> 
<div class="pc1s1">
  <h3 class="pc1s1Title">1rst semester</h3>
  <iframe class="pc1s1iframe" src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview? 
  id=1lyEGBCoXoACwwu8DOYbkUwHl1rrO_9rh" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IFrame height issues on iOS (mobile safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320046/iframe-height-issues-on-ios-mobile-safari)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this on your `.pc1s1iframe`

```
.pc1s1iframe {
  width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
}
```