# Iframe that's vertically scrollable and responsive in both ios safari and desktop chrome?

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile-safari

How can I have an iframe containing a large, responsive page inside of it that behaves properly for both desktop chrome and ios safari (assuming I don't control the iframe content)?  Consider a simple example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    html, body, iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src='https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo/Northeast'></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is pretty simple: a full-with and full-height iframe pointed at a misc large, responsive page.  The behavior I see:

- Desktop chrome: *good*.  The wikivoyage pages is desktop-sized and scrollable.
- Desktop chrome in iphone emulation mode: *good*.  The wikivoyage page is responsively-resized and scrollable.
- Actual Ios Safari (both physical phone and xcode iphone simulator): *bad*.  The wikivoyage page does not responsively resize– it shows the desktop-style page inside the iframe, which of course stretches way off the side of the page:

[image: ios safari behavior without scrollable=no]

Now, I can fix that last problem by adding `scrolling='no'` to the iframe as suggested in a number of stack overflow questions:

```
<iframe src='https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo/Northeast' scrolling='no'></iframe>
```

This works correctly on the iphone + ios simulator: the wikivoyage page is scrollable and responsively resized.  Predicatably, though, it breaks desktop chrome: the wikivoyage page isn't vertically scrollable there.  That makes sense– we just told it not to scroll.

It's entirely possible I'm just missing something in related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083462/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-be-responsive-in-ios-safari), but the accepted solution seems to suggest using `scrolling='no'`, which just breaks scrolling.  :(

TLDR: How can I get an iframe that's vertically scrollable *and* responsive in both ios safari and desktop chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a hacky solution I've come up with is to just have two iframes: one with `scrolling='no'` and one without, then just show the appropriate one on mobile:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      html, body, iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      @media (max-device-width: 740px) {
        .desktop-iframe { display: none; }
      }
      @media (min-device-width: 741px) {
        .iphone-iframe { display: none; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe class='iphone-iframe' scrolling='no' src='https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo/Northeast'></iframe>
    <iframe class='desktop-iframe' src='https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo/Northeast'></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, this *does* result in two requests to the iframe's webserver.  That'll induce some additional load and probably slow the page down a bit.  It seems better than any other option css-only soulution, though.