# Link cant be opened inside iframe on IOS

Tags: ios, iframe, hyperlink

I have a mobile app that uses iframe to show the html content.

I noticed that the link cant be opened on the IOS but its works well on android. Here's general example html code:

```
<iframe id="view-html-viewer-iframe" src="about:blank" frameborder="0">
...
<p><a href="https://google.com/" target="_parent">Google</a></p>
...
</iframe>
```

Anyone encounter the same issue.? is there any solution for this.?

Thanks.

Edit: the app is using kendo and cordova

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an IFrame to be responsive in iOS Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083462/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-be-responsive-in-ios-safari)

Comment: unfortunately no, there's no issue with the scroll itself. just when we try to open a link, it won't open.